# Does "Every infinite set is splittable" imply $\mathsf{AC}$?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

We say an infinite set $X$ is *splittable* if there are $X_1, X_2\subseteq X$ with $X_1\cap X_2 = \emptyset$, $X_1\cup X_2 = X$ and there are bijections $\varphi:X_1\to X_2$ and $\psi:X_1\to X$.

Does the statement "Every infinite set is splittable" imply $\mathsf{AC}$?

Comment: You might also be interested in this question, concerning two inequivalent concepts of even cardinalities: http://mathoverflow.net/q/69461/1946

Comment: I am almost sure that *you* asked this question not too long ago.

Comment: I was not wrong. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/230260/does-x-times-0-cup-x-times-1-leq-x-for-x-infinite-imply-s and also a follow up question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/230271/some-very-weak-statements-on-choice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is no and it follows from the following:

> It is consistent that $AC$ fails but for all infinite cardinals $\kappa, 2 \cdot \kappa=\kappa.$

The above result is proved by Sageev:

Sageev, Gershon [An independence result concerning the axiom of choice](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484375900029). Ann. Math. Logic 8 (1975), 1–184.

In a model as above, every infinite set is splittable but $AC$ fails in it.

Comment: Can you give a reference for this result, or at least some pointers for finding out more?  Without that, it’s pretty much just a rephrasing of the question.

Comment: I added a reference

Comment: Thanks Mohammad -- this $2\cdot(\ldots)$ argument was really the correct starting point!